# Installation in mac from bootable usb stick

Tags: installation

I have two installation issues. 
1) Trying to install UBUNTU in a macbook air mac osx, I can't seem to get past step 7: Run diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN **(replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2)**. Any suggestions?

2) I'm trying to install openFoam in a pc but can't seem to get it done either. In the pc it gives me an error of unable to find the file:

VERS=$(lsb_release -cs) 
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $VERS main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list"

sudo apt-get install openfoam211

Anybody know how to work around this issue? 
Thanks for any help on this matter.

Gerson

Answer (score 0):

In step 7, if you cannot unmount the disk with the `diskutil` command, open up OS X's the graphical Disk Utility. You will see the unmount option there, which may work.